# Generic error when modifying or adding new items to lists

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation

Hello I am currently receiving an error when trying to either add a new item (to only a certain list), or even change the name of a column (to all lists). The error simply says "Sorry, something went wrong" "An unexpected error has occurred." followed by a correlation ID and Date and Time.

EDIT:
Below is the message portion of the error log details for the correlationID I received:

PS C:\Users\USERNAME> get-splogevent | ?{$_.Correlation -eq "30106c9d-566f-7005
-4119-a618342a0faf"} | select Area, Category, Level, EventID, Message |Format-Li
st

---

Area     : SharePoint Foundation

Category : Logging Correlation Data

Level    : Medium

EventID  : xmnv

Message  : Name=Request (POST:http://SERVERNAME/SITE/PAGE/Lists/LISTNAME
           /NewFormV2.aspx?Source=http://SERVERNAME/SITE/PAGE/Si
           tePages/LISTNAME.aspx&RootFolder=)

---

Area     : SharePoint Foundation

Category : Request Management

Level    : Medium

EventID  : adc7u

Message  : Mapping URI from 'http://SERVERNAME:80/SITE/SUBSITE/Lists/LISTNAME
           /NewFormV2.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2FSERVER%2DNAME%2DSERVERNAME%2FSITE%2
           Dcenter%2FSUBSITE%2FSitePages%2FLISTNAME%2Easpx&RootFolder=' to 'http:
           //CRN-COGNOS-01/SITE/SUBSITE/Lists/LISTNAME/NewFormV2.aspx?Sour
           ce=http%3A%2F%2FSERVER%2DNAME%2DSERVERNAME%2FSITE%2Dcenter%2FSUBSITE%2FSitePage
           s%2FLISTNAME%2Easpx&RootFolder='

---

Area     : SharePoint Foundation

Category : Logging Correlation Data

Level    : Medium

EventID  : xmnv

Message  : Name=Request (POST:http://SERVERNAME:80/SITE/SUBSITE/Lists/LISTNAME
           /NewFormV2.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2FSERVER%2DNAME%2DSERVERNAME%2FSITE%
           2Dcenter%2FSUBSITE%2FSitePages%2FLISTNAME%2Easpx&RootFolder=)

---

Area     : SharePoint Foundation

Category : Authentication Authorization

Level    : Medium

EventID  : agb9s

Message  : Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True,
           UserIdentityName=0#.w|crisisnetwork\USERNAME, ClaimsCount=41

---

Area     : SharePoint Foundation

Category : General

Level    : Medium

EventID  : 8nca

Message  : Application error when access
           /SITE/SUBSITE/Lists/LISTNAME/NewFormV2.aspx, Error=A
           potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
           client (ctl00$ctl30$g_592264f6_187a_4c30_8813_523d48f5b5eb$ff101$ctl
           00$ctl00$UserField$OriginalEntities="").   at
           System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String
           collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)     at Sys
           tem.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateHttpValueCollection(HttpValueCollection
           collection, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)     at
           System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()     at
           Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.GetParametersFromHttpRequest(SPSite
           site, Boolean bAuthenticated)     at
           Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite
           site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String ...

---

Area     : SharePoint Foundation

Category : Runtime

Level    : Unexpected

EventID  : tkau

Message  : System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous
           Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$ctl30$g_59226
           4f6_187a_4c30_8813_523d48f5b5eb$ff101$ctl00$ctl00$UserField$Original
           Entities="").    at
           System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String
           collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)     at Sys
           tem.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateHttpValueCollection(HttpValueCollection
           collection, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)     at
           System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()     at
           Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.GetParametersFromHttpRequest(SPSite
           site, Boolean bAuthenticated)     at
           Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite
           site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl,
           Boolean bNotAddToContext, Byte[] U...

---

Area     : SharePoint Foundation

Category : General

Level    : High

EventID  : ajlz0

Message  : Getting Error Message for Exception
           System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A
           potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
           client (ctl00$ctl30$g_592264f6_187a_4c30_8813_523d48f5b5eb$ff101$ctl
           00$ctl00$UserField$OriginalEntities="").     at
           System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String
           collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)     at Sys
           tem.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateHttpValueCollection(HttpValueCollection
           collection, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)     at
           System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()     at
           Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.GetParametersFromHttpRequest(SPSite
           site, Boolean bAuthenticated)     at
           Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite
           site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode,...

---

Area     : SharePoint Foundation

Category : General

Level    : Monitorable

EventID  : aat87

Message  :

---

Area     : SharePoint Foundation

Category : Micro Trace

Level    : Medium

EventID  : uls4

Message  : Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq,4 agb9s,3 8nca,0 tkau,0 ajlz0,18 aat87

---

Area     : SharePoint Foundation

Category : Monitoring

Level    : Medium

EventID  : b4ly

Message  : Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (POST:http://SERVERNAME:80/SITENAME
           /SUBSITE/Lists/LISTNAME/NewFormV2.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Fcrn%2
           Dcognos%2D01%2Fcall%2Dcenter%2FSUBSITE%2FSitePages%2FLISTNAME%2Easpx&R
           ootFolder=)). Execution Time=37.2562015563431

---

Area     : SharePoint Foundation

Category : Micro Trace

Level    : Medium

EventID  : uls4

Message  : Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq,1 adc7u

---

Area     : SharePoint Foundation

Category : Monitoring

Level    : Medium

EventID  : b4ly

Message  : Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (POST:http://SERVERNAME/SITENAME
           /SUBSITE/Lists/LISTNAME/NewFormV2.aspx?Source=http://SERVERNAME/
           SITE/SUBSITE/SitePages/LISTNAME.aspx&RootFolder=)). Execution
           Time=43.3427293133624

Comment: You need to get the logs by correlation ID. That will give you some idea as to where to start.

Comment: Nisarg, I found the correlation ID within the logs, but I am unable to decipher what it is saying. Anyway you can lend assistance?

Comment: @CalebFortner  Hello , can u share the log message to us?

Comment: I am getting a feeling there should be more messages here. Anyway, can you try making changes to list item via Quick Edit view and post if it worked or not? My guess is it will work.

Comment: What's weird is I can enter new items through the form and in quick edit on lists that do not have the People picker field. But on lists that do have the people picker field, I cannot add a new item from the form or Quick Edit. In this case, quick edit gives me the error symbol on the left but no message.

Comment: I have run get-splogevent | ?{$_.Correlation -eq "30106c9d-566f-7005
-4119-a618342a0faf"} | select Area, Category, Level, EventID, Message |Format-List   in management shell, and reposted the error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client" error means that some form of HTML was posted to the server in one of the fields. HTML when rerendered to the client poses a security risk (can contain script etc. i.e. may result in an XSS attack).

So posted raw HTML will trigger an exception server side to prevent this. Check if you are posting HTML, if so, encode it before posting.

Comment: You were correct, and helped lead me to the answer. I went to the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client) and @JacquesB mentioned the .NET 4 httpRunTime setting. I added the requestValidationMode="2.0" to the httpRunTime setting within my web.config file, rebooted the server, and it was working like normal!